# Add 0 where only two characters at end of string

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for an excel macro to look at a column of data and add a 0 where only 2 numbers exist at the end of the string.

I.e.

AAA/97

will become

AAA/097.

In the original sheet there will be a mixture of correct entries like the one above and erroneous ones, like the top example

I understand a formula would probably be easier but this is an extensive list so I feel a macro would be better suited.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking us to write one or help you with what you have already written?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that should do the trick. I have assumed you are not considering $ as numeric in this.

```
Sub AddZero()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
Dim chkBool As Boolean, char3 As String, char2 As String, char1 As String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'change this to suit your workbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change this to suit your sheet
Set rng = ws.Range("B:B") 'change this to suit your range
For Each Cell In rng
    If IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then
        Set rng = Nothing
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set wb = Nothing
        Exit Sub 'I have assumed that there will not be blank rows in the range
    End If
    '''''' start checking the numbers at the end of the string
    char3 = Mid(Cell.Value, Len(Cell.Value), 1)
    char2 = Mid(Cell.Value, Len(Cell.Value) - 1, 1)
    char1 = Mid(Cell.Value, Len(Cell.Value) - 2, 1)
    If IsNumeric(char3) And char3 <> "$" Then 'isnumeric check the next character
        If IsNumeric(char2) And char2 <> "$" Then
            If IsNumeric(char1) And char1 <> "$" Then
                chkBool = True
            End If
            If chkBool = False Then
                Cell.Value = Mid(Cell.Value, 1, Len(Cell.Value) - 2) & "0" & char2 & char3 'reform the cell value
            End If
            chkBool = False 'reset the check if there is already 3 numbers at the end of the string
        Else:
            Cell.Value = Mid(Cell.Value, 1, Len(Cell.Value) - 1) & "00" & char3
        End If
    Else:
        'Cell.Value = Mid(Cell.Value, 1, Len(Cell.Value) - 2) & "000" 'not sure if you need this but if no numbers found will mask the end with 000
    End If
Next Cell
Set rng = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

I think Dick's answer is best if you can use a delimiter if your delimiter is not always there or is different then mine would work better it really depends on your situation.

Comment: Thanks Clint.  I used Dicks to begin with and it works.  I'll certainly keep yours in mind if I run into any problems!

Comment: Chris you should give an up vote to the answers that you found useful.

Comment: Clint, I ran into problems and used your code too.  Thanks, you have been a great help.  I clicked the up arrow to give a vote - thanks!

Comment: Clint, what if there was only 1 digit i.e. ABC/1 - how would you tell it to put in the two 00s in front of 1?

Comment: I edited the code to solve that problem just using an else after the char2 check. I also added another else after the char3 check so if no numbers are found you can mask the end with "000" i just commented it out. Just uncomment if you need it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  This has given me a really good insight into VBA!   Are there any books you recommend?

Comment: Google and experimentation is the best book around. I bought a book for VBA years ago. Never again there is much more info and knowledge online.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use VBA as not everyone likes to open a workbook containing macros. Use a formula instead:

`=IF(LEN(A1)=6,LEFT(A1,4)&"0"&RIGHT(A1,2),A1)` if A1 contains the cell.

Copy downwards. This will be benign on "correct" cells.

Comment: I agree with your premise of using formulas instead of vba.  But your formula does not deal with those that already have a 3 digit tail, as Chris stated there would be.  using an if statement to see if there are three digits or not would work.

Comment: It deals with a 3 digit tail if the first digit is a 0. That's what I thought the OP meant. Let's see if they confirm.

Comment: Made it invariant on any 3 digit tail.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(LEN(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)+1,3))<3,(MID(A1,1,FIND("/",A1,1)))&"0"&(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)+1,3)),LEN(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)+1,3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add some error checking, but these are the basics

```
Public Sub MakeZero()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim vaSplit As Variant

    Const sDELIM As String = "/"

    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A100").Cells
        vaSplit = Split(rCell.Value, sDELIM)
        rCell.Value = vaSplit(0) & sDELIM & Format(Val(vaSplit(1)), "000")
    Next rCell

End Sub
```